# how to use initialSelectedRange in react-native-calendar-range-picker?

Tags: react-native, date, calendar

I am trying to use initialSelectedRange in react-native-calendar-range-picker. My requirement is to set of dates(and/or date ranges) as selected by default when calendar is opened first time. I tried the below code. initialSelectedRange seems to be not working. I am not getting the expected result. May i know if there is any suggestion to achieve this?.

```
<Calendar
                startDate={startDate}
                endDate={endDate}
                disabledBeforeToday
                default
                value={['2023-05-22']}
                backgroundColor={'green'}
                initialSelectedRange={{startDate: moment(<some date here>).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),endDate: moment(<some date here>).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}}
                onChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => { setMarkedStart(startDate);
                    setMarkedEnd(endDate); 
                    }}
                style={{
                    border: '1px solid gray',
                    container: {},
                    monthContainer: {backgroundColor:'#f0f8ff',borderRadius:20},
                    weekContainer:{borderRadius:20},
                    monthNameText: {},
                    borderRadius: 16,
                    dayNameText: {color:'#4682b4',borderRadius:20},
                    dayText: {color:'#4682b4',borderRadius:20},
                    dayTextColor: 'black',
                    holidayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
                    todayColor: 'blue',
                    disabledTextColor: '#Hex',
                    selectedDayTextColor: 'black',
                    selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#1e90ff',
                    selectedBetweenDayTextColor: 'black',
                    selectedBetweenDayBackgroundTextColor: '#778899',
                }}
            />
```

i need to do it like below(select 16th May to 19th May & 29th May to 30th May),

[image]